# H2o model training metrics log location

Tags: h2o

I am running grid search using H2o and I am trying to find out where the model stats for the completed training models are stored with H2o - Hadoop. Say, it runs 10 models as part of grid search and it crashes after completing 5 models. Where do I find the scores (and parameters) for the completed models and where do I find the parameters for the model it was running when h2o crashed. I can't find this log anywhere. I am assuming it should persist the data somewhere to show in H2o flow. I just can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

When the job is done you can access the log output with the “yarn logs”
command.

When you run h2o on hadoop it prints the appropriate (filled in with your job id) yarn log command to stdout.

it will look something like:

```
yarn logs -applicationId nnn
```

Comment: As the H2o cluster crashes in the middle of the grid search, this doesn't return any logs. So I was trying to find an intermediate location where H2o keeps track of these details. It shows the details in H2o flow UI. But after the crash, if I restart H2o, UI doesn't have any details about the models. Is it not stored in HDFS or somewhere?

Comment: Logs will appear once the yarn job completes.

Comment: As the H2o server crashes, yarn job is failing. Is there any place it temporarily logs the data?

Comment: I am looking for a location where it logs details about various models it tried and param/scores of each model.

Comment: What you want are the stdout and stderr captured by “yarn logs” and available from yarn once the job ends.  That’s how we have been debugging hadoop yarn jobs since 2014.  I don’t know how to put it any other way.